# How to split one response into several Vuex modules?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I've got a small Vue/Vuex/Rails app that I'm building and am trying to figure out the best way to handle this scenario.

Upon login or page refresh, I have a mixin that checks to see whether currentUser is in state. If it's not, it runs a call to my api to retrieve the currentUser, as well as that user's deeply nested relationships. Something like this:

```
currentUser: {
    ...user data
    groups: [
        categories: [
            items: [
                ...item data
            ]  
        ],
    ],
}
```

That api call lives in `user.module.js`. My question is, rather than storing the entire user object with all of its nested data in user state, is it possible to split out all of that data into separate modules (eg.: `groups.module.js`, `categories.module.js`, `items.module.js`)?

This would allow me to make a much simpler action and mutation by going straight to item in the `items.module.js`.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: It is possible and from what you're describing, it's what you should do. However, your question doesn't currently contain sufficient code for anyone to understand *"user's deeply nested relationships"* or their logic. Which means your question is nor currently answerable nor likely to be helpful for anyone with a similar problem in the future, each of the above reasons making your question *off-topic* on [SO].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely you should split them in multiple modules, otherwise, your data structure will get really difficult to deal and understand. After you have defined how will be structured your modules, when you get the `user` data you can `dispatch` as many `actions` you need to each module to populate their states.
I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/pXmYqV) to show you.